# Как продолжить цикл после исключения?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Столкнулся с тем, что когда появляется исключение цикл не продолжает свою работу, нужно это исправить. `While True` - не подходит, так как мне нужно найти несколько файлов.
Задача звучит так: По списку в `excel` найти файлы в директории и перекинуть их в нужную папку.

Мой код:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=tm,index=None)
filename = df+'.mp3'
f=filename
n = ('C:/Users/download/')
s = ('C:/files/')
for elem in f: //f- элементы в экселе
        print(elem)
        try:
            shutil.copy(n+elem, s+elem) //копирование элемента
            print('Я перекинул нужные файлы')

        except:
            print('Этот файл нам не подходит')
            continue
```

```
print(f) возвращает:                                      
session_id
0   487564.mp3
1   488653.mp3
2   488941.mp3
3   489108.mp3
4   489535.mp3
5   489580.mp3
6   489582.mp3
```

```
print(elem) возвращает:
session_id
```

Comment: Откуда я знаю что у вас вызывает ошибку? Какая это ошибка? на какой строке? Так много вопросов и так мало ответов...

Comment: @DaYa ошибок никаких нет, просто цикл продолжает один и тот же файл искать

Comment: Что находится в `f`?

Comment: @АлексейР обновил вопрос

Comment: Нет, вы всё-таки покажите, что выводит у вас строка `print(elem)`

Comment: а еще лучше, print(f)

Comment: @splash58 Если там `DataFrame`, то не уверен, что так будет лучше, но не помешает )

Comment: @splash58 print(f) возвращает:

Comment: @МихаилДужарь Всё это прямо в вопрос добавляйте. В комментарии не нужно

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил

Comment: В любом случае у вас проблема именно с перебором. Этот код в любом случае не может один и тот же элемент перебирать, он перебирает по очереди элементы `f`. Ну, посмотрим, что в данных.

Comment: Так, хорошо. А всё же что печатает `print(elem)`?

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вообще не перебираете элементы датафрейма. Фактически, вы перебираете его колонки (такой же эффект, как если перебирать словарь - вы будете перебирать только его ключи). Колонка в датафрейме у вас одна `session_id`, и такого файла у вас, конечно, нет. Перебрать значения этой колонки датафрейма можно так:

```
for elem in f['session_id']:
```

С обработкой исключений у вас нет проблемы, кроме той, что исключения нельзя игнорировать, их нужно хотя бы печатать, хотя проблема и не в этом, но если бы вы напечатали исключение, вы бы раньше поняли, в чём проблема:

```
        except ex:
            print('Возникла проблема')
            print(ex)
            # continue здесь не имеет смысла
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло!